# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications

I am trying to run the ionic android build on Mac and directly installing on the device.

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

I am running the above command.

But it is throwing this error:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:24957) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/manishkumar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/manishkumar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
```

I tried the below commands but it is throwing this error

```
android sdk
```

---

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "sdk"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

It is very confusing on Mac

System `macOS 10.14.2`

Comment: Regarding your command android sdk, the output is giving the valid commands, android list sdk or android list avd.

Comment: In your terminal run android create avd. Create your emulator and try ionic emulate android again.

Comment: both are throwing the same error `The "android" command is deprecated.`